# How to update the Delphi Object Inspector?

Tags: delphi

Following on from this question I recently posted: [Can a Component Editor be executed on multiple components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14802371/can-a-component-editor-be-executed-on-multiple-components)

I have created a ComponentEditor for a new component that when executed shows a TOpenDialog to select a configuration File. When a File is loaded I read the data and copy the values to the calling component (which is `Component` as this is a TComponentEditor).

There are no problems at all, except that the Object Inspector is not updating to reflect the newly changed values - It only updates when clicking back on the component in the Designer.

It might not seem like such a big a deal, but I need the Object Inspector to update itself somehow so that I can see the properties have changed successfully (without having to switch focus back to the control).

So, is there some way of letting Delphi know that it should update/refresh the Object Inspector? I

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After modifying the component as needed, your component editor needs to call the `IDesigner.Modified()` method, eg:

```
procedure TMyComponentEditor.ExecuteVerb(Index: Integer);
var
  Dlg: TOpenDialog;
begin
  ...
  Dlg := TOpenDialog.Create(nil);
  try
    ...
    if Dlg.Execute then
    begin
      ...
      Designer.Modified;
    end;
  finally
    Dlg.Free;
  end;
  ...
end;
```

Comment: perfect thanks, I will have to remember the `Designer` keyword.

Comment: It is not a keyword, it is a property of `TComponentEditor`.