# Object Inspector update (Delphi 7)

Tags: delphi

I'm writing a component and ran into a problem I can't solve alone.

Let's say the component have two properties, one is Enumerated and the other one is inherited from TPersistent. This component is in a runtime package. Here is the code (simplified):

```
TxInputType = (itString, itNumber, itDateTime, itBoolean);

TxInputProperty = class(TPersistent);

TxStringProperty = class(TxInputProperty)
published
  property MaxLenght: integer ...;
end;

TxNumberProperty = class(TxInputProperty)
published
  property AllowNegative: boolean ...;
  property AllowZero: boolean ...;
  property Decimals: integer ...;
end;

TxInputComp = class(TComponent)
published
  property InputType: TxInputType read FInputType write SetInputType default itString;
  property Properties: TxInputProperty read FProperties write FProperties;
end;
```

When I change the InputType property in Object Inspector I recreate the Properties' object according to the actual InputType, so there will be different subproperties visible in the OI. So far, so good, works fine.

The problem comes when the Properties property is expanded in the OI, in this case when I change the InputType I get an IDE error (*Access violation at address XXXXXXXX in module 'rtl70.bpl'. Read of address YYYYYYYY.*, the call stack can be found below) and the OI wont updates the Properties property, unless if I collapse and expand again manually. If Properties collapsed i get no error.

I tried to solve the problem writing a custom design time property editor in a separated, design time package, i thought adding the "**paVolatileSubProperties**" will solve the problem.

```
TxInputTypePropEditor = class(TEnumProperty)
public
  function GetAttributes: TPropertyAttributes; override;
end;

...

function TxInputTypePropEditor.GetAttributes: TPropertyAttributes;
begin
  Result := [paValueList, paVolatileSubProperties];
end;
```

Nothing really changed, the original problem still exists.

How can I avoid causing exception and force the OI to reflect the changes?

Please note, the code is simplified, only a small part of the full source, it may contains errors.

Error call stack:

```
40005f4a +002 rtl70.bpl       System         TObject.InheritsFrom
40005e8e +00e rtl70.bpl       System         @IsClass
079eec3b +0e3 designide70.bpl Designeditors  TPropertyEditor.GetIsDefault
40019516 +012 rtl70.bpl       Sysutils       Supports
07946ea7 +3cb vclide70.bpl    Ideinsplistbox TInspListBox.DrawPropItem
0794671e +036 vclide70.bpl    Ideinsplistbox TInspListBox.CNDrawItem
07841a98 +188 vcl70.bpl       Controls       TControl.WndProc
07844c97 +157 vcl70.bpl       Controls       TWinControl.WndProc
07841868 +024 vcl70.bpl       Controls       TControl.Perform
078455a6 +00e vcl70.bpl       Controls       TWinControl.WMDrawItem
07841a98 +188 vcl70.bpl       Controls       TControl.WndProc
07844c97 +157 vcl70.bpl       Controls       TWinControl.WndProc
07844914 +02c vcl70.bpl       Controls       TWinControl.MainWndProc
7752505b +04b ntdll.dll                      KiUserCallbackDispatcher
766238ea +06a USER32.dll                     SendMessageW
76612056 +016 USER32.dll                     CallWindowProcA
07844d7b +0d7 vcl70.bpl       Controls       TWinControl.DefaultHandler
07946227 +00b vclide70.bpl    Ideinsplistbox TInspListBox.WMPaint
07841a98 +188 vcl70.bpl       Controls       TControl.WndProc
07844c97 +157 vcl70.bpl       Controls       TWinControl.WndProc
07844914 +02c vcl70.bpl       Controls       TWinControl.MainWndProc
7752505b +04b ntdll.dll                      KiUserCallbackDispatcher
7727121a +00a win32u.dll                     NtUserCallHwndLock
7662285a +03a USER32.dll                     UpdateWindow
07847225 +015 vcl70.bpl       Controls       TWinControl.Update
0794765a +02a vclide70.bpl    Ideinsplistbox TInspListBox.SetUpdateState
07947611 +019 vclide70.bpl    Ideinsplistbox TInspListBox.EndUpdate
079445d0 +19c vclide70.bpl    Ideinsplistbox TInspListBox.SetPropValue
023f5dbd +0dd coreide70.bpl   Propinsp       TPropertyInspector.PropListEditDblClick
07945549 +015 vclide70.bpl    Ideinsplistbox TInspListBox.EditDblClick
07841c55 +015 vcl70.bpl       Controls       TControl.DblClick
07841db8 +034 vcl70.bpl       Controls       TControl.WMLButtonDblClk
07841a98 +188 vcl70.bpl       Controls       TControl.WndProc
07844c97 +157 vcl70.bpl       Controls       TWinControl.WndProc
07943463 +037 vclide70.bpl    Ideinsplistbox TPropInspEdit.WndProc
07844914 +02c vcl70.bpl       Controls       TWinControl.MainWndProc
76615d7b +00b USER32.dll                     DispatchMessageA
0786568b +083 vcl70.bpl       Forms          TApplication.ProcessMessage
078656c2 +00a vcl70.bpl       Forms          TApplication.HandleMessage
078658f2 +096 vcl70.bpl       Forms          TApplication.Run
759bfa27 +017 KERNEL32.DLL                   BaseThreadInitThunk
```

Comment: If you want the Object Inspector to be updated. I think you need to call Designer.Modified in your design-time code.

Comment: The TEnumProperty.Modified is already called automatically in the SetValue method when the property changes, checked that. It is possible I still have to call that from my code, but in this case I have no idea when?

Comment: TBH, I'm not quite sure how what you're asking relates to my comment, but you may find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14823935/2663863) helpful,

Comment: I have seen that topic, but that is releated to a TComponentEditor. I'm using TEnumProperty which is a property editor. The question which method should I override to call Designer.Modified? The Designer.Modified is already called in the base class' SetValue() method.

Comment: What is the exact error when you expand the `Properties` property?

Comment: I forgot to mention that, updated the topic, thanks. (Access violation at address XXXXXXXX in module 'rtl70.bpl'. Read of address YYYYYYYY.)

Comment: Also included the call stack.